# PyCharm Remote Interpreter: Cannot Execute Docker's Python Binary

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, remote-debugging, remote-server

I have configured PyCharm to target the Python binary in my Docker container, but am getting this error:

```
Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter
failed to run generator3.py for docker://app:latest//usr/local/python/bin/python, exit code 126, stderr: ----- /usr/local/python/bin/python: /usr/local/python/bin/python: cannot execute binary file -----
```

Running PyCharm 5.0.4 with Docker 1.10.0 in a VM with Python 3.4.3.

Here are my PyCharm Remote Interpreter settings:
[image]

Saving those settings gives a `Non-zero exit code.` and the above error.

Answer (score 5):

In the `Dockerfile` of your docker image you will probably find an **ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]** or similar. PyCharm will try to run the interpreter like so :

`docker run app:latest /usr/local/python/bin/python`

In combination with the ENTRYPOINT that results in the following command within the container:

`bash /usr/local/python/bin/python`

From that the error message makes sense. If you have control over the Dockerfile you can either change the **ENTRYPOINT** to **CMD** or - if that's not an option for you - change the entrypoint so that it can work with `/usr/local/python/bin/python` as parameter and do the right thing with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using Docker Compose before PyCharm fully supported it, which didn't really start to happen until [PyCharm 2016.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/03/announcing-general-availability-of-pycharm-2016-1/). The PyCharm blog [posted](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/03/docker-compose-getting-flask-up-and-running/) about how to use it with Docker Compose about a month after I asked this question.